Deploy in ArgoCD does't seem to be able to take in boolean value

UPDATE - I made a mistake while checking my envars and read the wrong
side of the mapping. My name matches what the program uses but not
what the docker file maps to it. Take the error message seriously kids

I have a problem with a deployment within ArgoCD that seems to be failing, and I cannot understand why. Here is the error:
 Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'boolean'; Invalid boolean value []
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798)

Error clearly lays out that the app is not able to get the boolean passed in. Problem is I can't find why this would be the case. Looking at the environment variable I can verify it is there, and should therefore be passed in.
The apps is Java 17, and Spring boot, and here are the argo specs:
{
    "Version": "v2.11.2+25f7504",
    "BuildDate": "2024-05-23T13:32:13Z",
    "GitCommit": "25f7504ecc198e7d7fdc055fdb83ae50eee5edd0",
    "GitTreeState": "clean",
    "GoVersion": "go1.21.9",
    "Compiler": "gc",
    "Platform": "linux/amd64",
    "KustomizeVersion": "v5.2.1 2023-10-19T20:13:51Z",
    "HelmVersion": "v3.14.4+g81c902a",
    "KubectlVersion": "v0.26.11",
    "JsonnetVersion": "v0.20.0"
}

What I have tried:
I have played with passing in as a String, boolean, or even a number. Adding a default through spring and various little config adjustments.
What I expect:
The app to read in the passed in boolean

that error sounds like its everything to do w/ an app code issue (ie casting a type "string" to "bool"). In your app code, try supplying a string "true" or "false" to where the env var is read in - this should be resolvable via unit testing. Also - make sure your stringified bool has all whitespace trimmed

Makes sense @LostJon but this was not changed for the deploy and worked previously which leads me to believe this is more an argocd quirk we triggered by accident.

Well... @LostJon apparently i messed up when checking the envar spelling. It matches what the program uses but not what docker takes in so it was never properly mapped when the container was launched. I know better and even checked for this and still made the mistake...
